# Difference between a space and a "wave" symbol (tilde/"~")?

Tags: symbols

As title, what is the difference between a   and `~`?

I see no differences after the compilation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}

\author{You}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

I am cool.

I~am~cool.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You will see the difference at end of line. `~` is unbreakable space where as space isn't unbreakable.

Comment: "I am cool"... That's a rather bold statement `:p`

Comment: It controls space too, it's very often used after a `\the....` counter output command.

Comment: In text mode `~`=`\nobreakspace`

Comment: @yo' Should I delete this questions, then?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't found the other question when write this one :( And don't worry if it's closed, you guys help me a lot :d

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference can be seen at the end of line. A space is breakable and a `~` is an un-breakable space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Your Paper}

\author{You}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\hspace*{0.9\textwidth}I am cool.

\hspace*{0.9\textwidth}I~am~cool.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The three words `I` `am` and `cool` are glued together in the second line.

Answer (score 22):

The `~` is an *active character*, which means it's the same as a macro like `\mbox` and so on. Its function is described by its definition, which is

```
\nobreakspace{}
```

so typing `~` is equivalent to typing `\nobreakspace{}`.

What does `\nobreakspace` do? Here it is:

```
\leavevmode\nobreak\
```

(a space follows the last backslash). So a paragraph is started or nothing is done if we're already in a paragraph (`\leavevmode`); then `\nobreak` is issued, which disallows any line break at the point (`\nobreak`) and then a normal interword space is inserted.

Thus when typing

```
no~break
```

there will be a space between the two words, but the line will not be broken after `no`.

---

Why the `{}` after `\nobreakspace`? If you have `no~break` in a caption, in the `.aux` file the expanded version will appear

```
no\nobreakspace  {}break
```

The braces have been introduced to cope with the rare case when a space after `~` is wanted; without them `no~ break` would write

```
no\nobreakspace   break
```

and, upon reading the `.aux` file, the space would be ignored. With the braces

```
no\nobreakspace  {} break
```

will be written and the additional space would not be ignored.

---

What happens if one types `no~ break` in the output? Two spaces are added but no line break at them is possible, because a space is a feasible line break point only if it is not preceded by a discardable item; since `\nobreakspace` becomes

```
\leavevmode\penalty 10000 \
```

and penalties are discardable like spaces, neither `\`  nor the following space can be used for a line break.

In the reverse case `no ~break` two spaces are output, but now a break point is possible at the first space (and both will disappear together with the penalty in case it is taken).

Comment: Nice explanation. Can I say +1?

Comment: You speak about the `no~ break` but not about `no ~break`. In particuler this case may appear when using a char limitation per line with a line return intead of the space. What happen in this case?

Comment: @RomainPicot Almost the same, you get two spaces if no break happens, but a break is possible (which is not with `no~ break)`

Comment: @egreg thank you for the precision `;-)`

Comment: @RomainPicot I added a final note, thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

This is the definition of `~` in `latex.ltx`

```
\catcode `\~=13
\def~{\nobreakspace{}}
```

while `\nobreakspace` is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{%
   \leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

So, the active character `~` is equivalent to a space that cannot be broken into lines.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover what `~` is and does.  The most common reason *why* I use it is when I want to say something like "Figure 1" or "Theorem 2", where having a space before the number (along with unfortunate line breaking) could cause the number to appear as the first thing on the next line.  This would look a bit as if I wanted to start an enumeration, which is not my intent.  Therefore, I would write `Figure~1` or `Theorem~2` in my code to prevent that from happening.

In general, you should let TeX decide on the line breaking for itself, and not litter your code with too many `~`.  The downside of using it is that you end up with an unbreakable box, which makes line breaking difficult.  In the "I~am~cool" example of the accepted answer, for example, the box probably extends into the right margin, which is unsightly and causes an overfull hbox warning.